# PyQGIS - Changing scalebar width from an existing layout

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, scale-bar

I have a project on QGIS 3.16 with several layouts.
I would like to change the scalebar width according to the value of a Python variable, either a fixed sized of 1000 or 500 units (for instance).

First, I tried to do it without the Python variable, by using the value of 1000 units.
I think the following code I use try to create a new scalebar, instead of calling the existing one.
Here, the name of the actual layout is 'cumul_eoliennes':

(once the QGIS projet is opened)

```
project = QgsProject.instance() 
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
composeur_eol = 'cumul_eoliennes'
layout_eol= projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(composeur_eol)
scalebar=QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout_eol)

scalebar.setHeight(1)
 # scalebar.height() gives the default value of 3 mm
scalebar.setFixedSize(1000)
```

The last code gives :

> TypeError: QgsLayoutItemScaleBar.setFixedSize(): argument 1 has
> unexpected type 'int

In conclusion, I meet two problems:

- it seems I am not able to call the actual scalebar of a layout
- I don't know how to change the "FixedSize" of a scalebar

[EDIT about the FixedSize]
I am looking for the scalebar fixed size function like below:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This line in your code: `scalebar=QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout_eol)` is creating a new `QgsLayoutItemScaleBar` object. This is not the way to access an existing scale bar object. In order to do that you can do something like:

```
scale_bar = [i for i in layout_eol.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemScaleBar)][0]
```

Which works fine if you only have one scale bar in your layout. Alternatively, you could use the method [itemById()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html#a00b4d410f78289b08bcce5d2e92c81ae).

For your second problem, the [setFixedSize()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItem.html#af6e2fe4f797a104dc40854958f0cf976) method takes a [QgsLayoutSize()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutSize.html#a6de1d4bb2e3204037b4f42dbd5985722) argument. The QgsLayoutSize() class constructor takes width and height arguments as well as a units argument which defaults to `QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters`.

Try the following:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance() 
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
composeur_eol = 'cumul_eoliennes'
layout_eol= projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(composeur_eol)
scale_bar = [i for i in layout_eol.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemScaleBar)][0]
#print(scale_bar)
scale_bar.setFixedSize(QgsLayoutSize(100, 20))
```

Comment: Excellent solution to access an existing scale bar! Thank you. However, I realize the function to change scalebar width is not FixedSize which is the one of the box containing the scale bar. I have edited my post with a screenshort of the function I am looking for. I assume first I have to set up the size mode to "fixed size" using scale_bar.setSegmentSizeMode(0). But then, how I can change the width value?

Comment: Try `scale_bar.setUnitsPerSegment(1000)` (tested, so it should work) You can play manually with your units in the GUI and then use `scale_bar.unitsPerSegment()` to confirm.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help. Last question regarding the initial goal: how shoud I write the Python variable associated to this value (e.g. 1000)? I tried: scale_width='1000' and scale_bar_eol.setUnitsPerSegment(scale_width) but I got an error about "str" type. I tried with simple and double quotes too... I guess this is basic Python but I am newby.

Comment: Just 1000 with no quotes, exactly as per @ThomasG77's comment. The method takes a double as argument which in C++ is a datatype which holds numerical data e.g. not a string! So passing an integer value in the Python bindings works fine.

Comment: I think I missed something on the first place, since no quotes works fine indeed: scale_width=1000 and scale_bar_eol.setUnitsPerSegment(scale_width). Thanks!